# Pyramid: How to specify the base URL for the application

Tags: python, config, pyramid

Let's say my app is served at the domain `www.example.com`.

How (where?) should I specify this in the Pyramid configuration file so that functions like `request.route_url` would automatically pick it and generate the correct URL.

(I think `[server:main]` is not the place for this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url generation functions `route_url`, `static_url`, `resource_url` all depend on the WSGI environ dictionary from where they take all the essential parameters required to generate a full URL.

Hence one way to do it is to modify the WSGI environment dictionary at the request creation time, and modify the required parameters. Events are great for this kind of thing:

```
from pyramid.events import NewRequest
from pyramid.events import subscriber

@subscriber(NewRequest)
def mysubscriber(event):
    event.request.environ['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.com'
```

After this, `route_url` will take `example.com` as the base URL.

Comment: To clarify, Pyramid generates URLs relative to the **current** request. It has no concept of being hosted at a specific or singular prefix.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel Yes, that's correct. One question though: If you put your Pyramid app behind (say) Nginx, wouldn't it be better to send the HTTP_HOST (and others) via Nginx config. That way you make your app completely generic. It would also rid us of the overhead of executing the NewRequest event handler.

Comment: The other useful thing to override is `environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'`, if your frontend proxy does HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a proper reverse proxy will forward along the appropriate headers to your wsgi server. See the pyramid cookbook for an nginx recipe.